# What is the correct lambda expression to return hierarchical data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda, hierarchical-data

I'm using Entity Framework with the following SQL table

Table `TestParentChilds`:

```
id   name   parent
------------------
1    John   null
2    Bill   1
3    Jane   2
4    Bob    2
```

`id` is the primary key and `parent` is a foreign key - table has a self reference. I have two navigation properties in EF called `[Subordinates]` (multiplicity  *Many) and `[Manager]` (multiplicity 1 or 0)

I get weird results using the following lambda expression

```
/ * DAL code */
ManagePlayEntities ctx = new ManagePlayEntities();
return ctx.TestParentChilds.ToArray()
```

I need help with lambda expression to return hierarchical data.

Comment: Can you clarify "weird results"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I may have inadvertently answered my own question

Below expresison appears to give me what I'm looking for.

return ctx.TestParentChilds.Where(e =>  e.Manager.manageId==e.manageId).ToArray();